# Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException:

Tags: php, dns

Good afternoon, I just started working with domains in PHP.
The code isn't finished yet but before I try to put it inside a database I want it to properly work. But I got a fatal error and if I proceed I'll get a 404 not found error. The fatal error is this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid syntax in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\Classes\domain.php:23 Stack trace:
>
> 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\login\logins.php(25): Whois->__construct('')
>
> 1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\Classes\domain.php on line 23

The line of code in question is this:

```
$whois_answer = $domain->info();
```

I really don't know how to fix this one...

```
<?php
            require ("Classes/domain.php");
        
            $search = "";
            echo "<form action='login.php' method='get'>";
            echo "<p>Qual é o domínio que deseja procurar?</p><br>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='search' value=''><br><br>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='search2' value='Procurar'>";
            echo "</form>";
            if (!empty ($_GET['search'])){
                $search = $_GET['search'];
            }
            $sld = $search;
            //var_dump($search);
            
            //$sld = 'larousse.fr';
            $domain = new Whois($sld);
            
            $whois_answer = $domain->info();
            
            $answer= preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $whois_answer);
```

and the domain.php:

```
<?php
class Whois
{
    private $domain;
    private $TLDs;
    private $subDomain;
    private $servers;

    public function __construct($domain)
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;
        if ( preg_match('/^([\p{L}\d\-]+)\.((?:[\p{L}\-]+\.?)+)$/ui', $this->domain, $matches) || preg_match('/^(xn\-\-[\p{L}\d\-]+)\.(xn\-\-(?:[a-z\d-]+\.?1?)+)$/ui', $this->domain, $matches)){
        $this->subDomain = $matches[1];
        $this->TLDs = $matches[2];
    } else
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid $domain syntax");
      $this->servers = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/whois.servers.json' ), true);
}
public function info()
{
    if ($this->isValid()) {
        $whois_server = $this->servers[$this->TLDs][0];
        if ($whois_server != '') {
            if (preg_match("/^https?:\/\//i", $whois_server)) {
                $ch = curl_init();
                $url = $whois_server . $this->subDomain . '.' . $this->TLDs;
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                if (curl_error($ch)) {
                    return "Connection error!";
                } else {
                    $string = strip_tags($data);
                }
                curl_close($ch);
            } else {
                $fp = fsockopen($whois_server, 43);
                if (!$fp) {
                    return "Connection error!";
                }
                $dom = $this->subDomain . '.' . $this->TLDs;
                fputs($fp, "$dom\r\n");
                $string = '';
                if ($this->TLDs == 'com' || $this->TLDs == 'net') {
                   while (!feof($fp)) {
                       $line = trim(fgets($fp, 128));
                       $string .= $line;
                       $lineArr = explode (":", $line);
                       if (strtolower($lineArr[0]) == 'whois server') {
                           $whois_server = trim($lineArr[1]);
                       }
                    }
                    $fp = fsockopen($whois_server, 43);
                    if (!$fp) {
                        return "Connection error!";
                    }
                    $dom = $this->subDomain . '.' . $this->TLDs;
                    fputs($fp, "$dom\r\n");
                    $string = '';
                    while (!feof($fp)) {
                        $string .= fgets($fp, 128);
                    }
                } else {
                    while (!feof($fp)) {
                        $string .= fgets($fp, 128);
                    }
                }
                fclose($fp);
            }
            $string_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true);
            $string_utf8 = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", $string_encoding);
            return htmlspecialchars($string_utf8, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", true);
        } else {
            return "No whois server for this tld in list!";
        }
    } else {
        return "Domain name isn't valid!";
    }
}
public function htmlInfo()
{
    return nl2br($this->info());
}
public function getDomain()
{
    return $this->domain;
}
public function getTLDs()
{
    return $this->TLDs;
}
public function getSubDomain()
{
    return $this->subDomain;
}
public function isAvailable()
{
    $whois_string = $this->info();
    $not_found_string = '';
    if (isset($this->servers[$this->TLDs][1])) {
       $not_found_string = $this->servers[$this->TLDs][1];
    }
    $whois_string2 = @preg_replace('/' . $this->domain . '/', '', $whois_string);
    $whois_string = @preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', $whois_string);
    $array = explode (":", $not_found_string);
    if ($array[0] == "MAXCHARS") {
        if (strlen($whois_string2) <= $array[1]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/" . $not_found_string . "/i", $whois_string)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
public function isValid()
{
    if (
        isset($this->servers[$this->TLDs][0])
        && strlen($this->servers[$this->TLDs][0]) > 6
    )
    {
        $tmp_domain = strtolower($this->subDomain);
        if (
            preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]{3,}$/", $tmp_domain)
            && !preg_match("/^-|-$/", $tmp_domain) //&& !preg_match("/--/", $tmp_domain)
        )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: We need to see more code to help. Can you show both the Whois `__construct` method and the rest of domain.php?

Comment: sure, I'll just edit in my question

Comment: What is in line 23 of `domain.php`?

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st - Thank you for trying to help me.
2nd - the solution was that:

```
echo "<form action='logins.php' method='get'>";
```

in logins.php the file was misspelled, I've put login.php in stead of logins.php;

and the `if` was just too short, if I include the rest of the program it'll be all okay.